# PSCustomObject Check Multiple Computers for folder

Tags: powershell, directory, registry, profile

I am trying to check for presence of a particular folder "appdata\Local\Packages\ActiveSync" in each of the profile folders that are returned for each of the computer by the below script.Searching through various forums I got the script below and need further assistance to eventually output it to a file with results of  Test-Path against each computer name and corresponding profile path.
e.g. `\\Computer1\C:\users\John\appdata\Local\packages\ActiveSync False`

```
Invoke-Command -Computer (get-content c:\temp\servers.txt) -ScriptBlock {
 Get-childItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList' |
  % {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath }}  |  Select pscomputername,profileimagepath |
  Where-Object { $_.ProfileImagePath -like "C:\users*" } | Out-File c:\temp\profiles.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, I think I would use a loop to go through all user path strings like below:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName (Get-Content -Path 'c:\temp\servers.txt') -ScriptBlock {
    $regPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\*'
    Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $regPath -Name 'ProfileImagePath' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Where-Object { $_ -like 'C:\Users*' } | ForEach-Object {
        # combine the value with the rest of the path to form a LOCAL path
        $path = Join-Path -Path $_ -ChildPath 'AppData\Local\Packages\ActiveSync'
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
            Path         = '\\{0}\{1}' -f $env:COMPUTERNAME, ($path.Replace(":", "$"))  # UNC format
            Exists       = Test-Path -Path $path -PathType Container
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\temp\profiles.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Please note that if the output should be a structured CSV file, you need to use `Export-Csv` on the resulting objects instead of `Out-File`.
Also you may need to append parameter `-Credential` to the Invoke-Command call where you can give it administrative credentials.

Comment: @user2591459 Thanks for the feedback. Being new to the platform, may I point your attention to the [tour], where amongst other interesting stuff you can read how to mark a question 'done' if an answer solves your problem.